# VBA Copy data from an unopened CSV file to worksheet without opening closed CSV

Tags: csv, excel, vba

I believe I have a unique problem as I have not seen anything like it anywhere on the Internet.

I am a business analyst/application developer and I want to automatically gather the data from other user's Excel CSV file on their personal computer without opening the file and disrupting them. Is there a way?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyDocuments As String, strFileName, myToday, origWorkbook, origWorksheet, strConnection
Dim row As Integer

Private Sub btnStart_Click()
    MyDocuments = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents"
    myToday = Format(Date, "mmddyy")
    strFileName = "DataFile" & myToday & ".csv"
    strConnection = "TEXT;" & MyDocuments & "\DataFolder\" & strFileName
    origWorksheet = "DataFile" & myToday

    row = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    row = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row + 1

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=strConnection, Destination:=Range("$A$" & row))
        .Name = "temp"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Like I said, I don't want the CSV file to open while they are working. I would like this behind the scenes so they can keep working while we gather the data.

I'm guessing my biggest hang up is that it's a CSV file, that or that the file is not open. If there's a way this can be done, please let me know. Currently, I am getting an out of range error.

Comment: When I run your code it prints it out on the next row...

Comment: Could it be a setting of some sorts? Maybe in Excel? Every time I run the program, it puts the data in the next column.

Comment: is there data in `Column A` of your CSV file.  I just realized that if your first column is empty then no data will be copied into excel and the statement `row = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row + 1` will not work and the row variable will stay equal to 1.  Change the `Range("A1")` to a column you know that data will be copied into so it actually counts the rows down to the next row

Comment: I updated my example to add logic to first look for the first data towards the right of "A1" and then look to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to just grab the data and put it in your current workbook.  I recorded a macro using the Data -> Import Data method and in VBA and it seems to work with the CSV file closed:

**Print to consecutive column:**

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim MyDocuments, strFileName, myToday, file, strConnection As String

    MyDocuments = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents"
    myToday = Format(Date, "mmddyy")
    strFileName = "DataFile" & myToday & ".csv"

    strConnection = "TEXT;" & MyDocuments & "\DataFolder\" & strFileName
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
         strConnection, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "temp"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

**Print to consecutive row:**

Here we have to add

```
Dim row As Integer
    row = 1
    On Error Resume Next

    row = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown).row + 1
```

and then instead of: `Destination:=Range("$A$1")`
we use the row variable: `Destination:=Range($A$" & row)`

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim MyDocuments, strFileName, myToday, file, strConnection As String

    MyDocuments = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents"
    myToday = Format(Date, "mmddyy")
    strFileName = "DataFile" & myToday & ".csv"

    Dim row As Integer
    row = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    row = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row + 1

    strConnection = "TEXT;" & MyDocuments & "\DataFolder\" & strFileName
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
         strConnection, Destination:=Range("$A$" & row))
        .Name = "temp"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

This will grab all of the CSV data and put it in `A1` you can change the `$A$1` to whatever location you want.  Of course you can change all of the other variables also, I just recorded the macro and edited the `strConnection` variable to match the location you described in your question.

Hopefully this is what you are looking for, if not let me know.

Comment: Is the "TEXT;" a constant variable representing anything that I have within the Range of the closed CSV?

Comment: TEXT is the format you are importing if you look at `Get External Data` you have different options like `From Access`, `From Web`, `From Text`, etc

Comment: Ok...next question. It's printing any consecutive calls to the closed CSV in the columns to the right. How do I get it to print on the next empty row down? I believe I can use Offset(1, 0), correct?

Comment: It's still printing in the consecutive column. I looked what you wrote over a couple times and I have everything...not sure what I missed.

Comment: I don't know how to enter my code without starting a new question. I have everything you have and it still puts the data in the next column, not the next row.

Comment: Can anyone help me? I have my code looking exactly like the code above and it constantly puts the data in the next empty column instead of the next empty row.

Comment: @user2572769 I would need to see your code, perhaps edit your question and post it there

Comment: @user2572769 I re-tested both the macros I posted and they are working fine for me as I described so I would need to see exactly what you have.